# XCUI Test: How to fetch List of elements from the iOS screen

Tags: java, appium-ios, appium-android, xcuitest

I have recently started automating iOS apps on iPhone real devices with the XCUI test setup.

I got a scenario where my app contains 5 screens in the home page, each screen contains a unique card number and its balance so i have to fetch the card number from the screen and verify it with my input(expected) card number, if both are same then i have to click on the card screen otherwise if both are not same then i have to swipe right to the second screen and do the same process.

I was able to automate this scenrio in android perfectly because in android each screen is clearly differentiated with a unique card number but when i inspect the card number screen on iOS app it was showing all the list of cards attached to the app. in this case its getting difficult for me to get the card number from the app and verify it with my input card number . please see the below code which am already using it for android

```
String oysterCardVisibleNumberOnApp= data.get("PrestigeCardNumber");


while(!action.getText(HomePage.oysterCardNumber,"oysterCardNumber").equalsIgnorecase(oysterCardVisibleNumberOnApp))){
      action.swipeRightToLeft();
     }
```

it would be great if any one has any idea how to retrieve the list of elements/cards from the iOS app please let me know. or if you know any new methods in XCUI setup will help me to achieve this then please let me know. your help will be much appreciated :)

Please see the below Android Screen & iOS Screen pictures for getting more clarity

[Android Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSyLW.png)

[iOS Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG1nP.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use the Accessibility Inspector in xcode for this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXTestingApps.html

Based on areas you select in your app, it gives back detailed descriptions on each one. But what it brings back depends on the structure of your application. I was trying to do something similar in my own ios application and this helped me a bit.

Comment: thanks for pointing me out to the Accessibility inspector concept but i was wondering like every where i see this Accessibility inspector works for iOS simulator version only. i would want to know if this works for inspecting iPhone real devices too, because am testing my app on iPhone real device

Comment: @kumar No problem. Unfortunately you cannot use it on real devices but i found an interesting page on testing your app on real devices using Apples VoiceOver technology: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/TestingAccessibilityOfiOSApps/TestAccessibilityonYourDevicewithVoiceOver/TestAccessibilityonYourDevicewithVoiceOver.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012619-CH3-SW1

Answer (score 5):

If you stop at a breakpoint for instance and you use:

`po XCUIApplication().descendants(matching: .any)`

in the debug console, you will get a list of all descendant elements from the main Application element. It will also give you a loose view of the structure.

You can then change `.any` to more specific element types e.g. `.textField` or `.buttons`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XCUIApplication().debugDescription` to get a print out of the UI tree that XCUITest sees. You can also update the application code to set custom identifiers for your UI elements (these are only seen by XCUITest). for example `card-1`, etc.